# paypal express checkout landingpage billing issue

Tags: html, forms, paypal

For some reason I can't get my paypal express checkout to allow guest-checkout without logging into paypal. I have the two vital form fields

```
        <input type="hidden" name="SOLUTIONTYPE" value="Sole" />
        <input type="hidden" name="LANDINGPAGE" value="Billing" />
```

but it still only shows login.

The full form looks like this (without products, normally there'd be item_1, item_2 and so forth):

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                   <input type="image" src="myimg.png" name="submit" class="wp_cart_checkout_button" alt="Betal med PayPal - det er hurtigt, gratis og sikkert!"><input type="hidden" name="return" value="return.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@email.dr">
                    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="DKK">
                    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="da_DK">
                    <input type="hidden" name="SOLUTIONTYPE" value="Sole">
                    <input type="hidden" name="LANDINGPAGE" value="Billing">
                    <input type="hidden" name="logoimg" value="logo.png">
                    <input type="hidden" name="PAYMENTACTION" value="Sale"> 
                    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
                    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're specifying this information in a , you're most likely not using Express Checkout.
Can you share the rest of your  code? I have a strong suspicion you're using Payments Standard instead.

With Payments Standard you can't force the billing or login page; it's determined by cookie. If a PayPal login cookie is found, it'll display the login page. If no login cookie is found, it will display the billing page.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I edited the question to include the full form code

Comment: Yeah, that's Payments Standard. So my answer applies.